# Cannot resolve keyword into field error while using drf model serializer and search_fields within field set?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

SerializerClass:

```
class VacancySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization_small_name = serializers.CharField(source='organization.short_name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Vacancy
        fields = ['organization', 'description', 'specs', 'type', 'publication_date',
                  'is_published', 'withdrawal_data', 'organization_small_name', ]
        read_only_fields = ['publication_date', 'is_published', 'withdrawal_data',]
```

ViewSet:

```
class VacancyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = Vacancy.objects.all()
      serializer_class = VacancySerializer
      filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
      search_fields = ['organization_small_name']
...
```

Model:

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
organization = models.OneToOneField(DictOrganization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vacancies')
description = models.TextField('Описание')
specs = models.ManyToManyField(DictSpec, blank=True)
type = models.CharField('Тип', max_length=20, choices=VacancyType.choices(), default=VacancyType.PRACTICE.value)

publication_date = models.DateField('Дата публикации', null=True, blank=True)
is_published = models.BooleanField('Опубликовано', default=False)
withdrawal_data = models.DateField('Дата снятия с публикации', null=True, blank=True)
```

My goal is to make API search by 'organization_small_name' field
that is in VacancySerializer.
Server runs successfully, but as soon as i add ?search parameter, i get next error:
[image]

Why it doesn't recognize 'organization_small_name' field, even thought it is decribed in serializer, and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "organization__small_name".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).